# Codeception "alias" step

Tags: api, bdd, codeception, acceptance

I have a rather simple question regarding output step messages in Codeception for which I found no answer in the documentation.

To be more precise: Is there anyway to "alter" the steps output in codeception using an alias?

This:

```
public function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->sendPOST('/', ['foo' => 'bar']);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
}
```

Will output:

```
I send post "/",{"foo":"bar"}
I see response code is 200
```

But I would like to alter the "content" with an alias so it can output:

```
I send post "/", NewCustomerRequest
I see response code is 200
```

Does Codeception have this capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Codeception has no such capability.

However the right place for such description is in the name of the test.

`public function NewCustomerRequest(ApiTester $I)`

Also you can use comment actions to add description to the output - `amGoingTo`, `expect`, `expectTo` and `comment`
https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Comments